# Reconfiguring a WiFi Access Point's wireless settings through WPS

Tags: wireless-networking, wps

I visited [Reconfiguring a WiFi Access Point's wireless settings through WPS?](https://superuser.com/questions/376362/reconfiguring-a-wifi-access-points-wireless-settings-through-wps/426951#426951)

When I'm running

```
wpa_cli -g /var/run/wpa_supplicant
```

it's opening further Interactive mode. But over here when I am writing

```
wps_reg 02:34:56:78:9a:bc 12345670 clear OPEN NONE ""
```

it's showing

> Invalid WPS_REG command: need two arguments:

Every time it's showing that error.